# node.js memory usage explodes on doing ~500k mongodb inserts

Tags: mysql, node.js, performance, mongodb

I am migrating data from MySQL to MongoDB.

The MySQL is not optimized at all (no indices) so my operations, 1 plain sql query and 1 sql sequelize query take ~30 secs each and return ~300k documents each.

I am not worried about the MySQL part though, but about the node/mongo part.

When inserting them into MongoDB, I have tried a couple of things:

- using native driver and array-inserts, I dont see any problems, it is fast. I simply aggregate the query results into several mid-size arrays (<16MB) and insert them. But I want to do upserts rather than inserts to not destroy modified data, and that is not supported for bulk operations.
- using mongoose and single upserts, the node process slowly goes towards the mem limit I gave it (3GB) and then seems to stall there. After 30 mins, there is little visible progress, mongodb process is at 0% CPU. (I think it typically finishes at some point a lot later, if it has enough memory for the given amount of data.)
- using native driver and single upserts, the whole process is running very slowly, but at least finishing. Watching the CPU usage in Task Manager (Windows System), I can see that the mysql is using CPU when it is supposed to (when I start the 2 queries, the 2nd after the first one is finished and all results have been inserted into mongodb (at least from the node side, since they have not actually arrived by then)) and that Mongod is showing CPU load briefly at the beginning, but then it stays at 0%, while node.js is grabbing more and more memory. Only much later the mongod seems to pick up again, and at some point the memory usage of node reverses and goes back to normal by the time that mongod also is coming back to 0% CPU.
  Strangely, by that time, all my queries/upserts are finished a long time ago, and the actual work (from what I can see from CPU usage as well as from the actual data in mongodb by having shell open at same time and counting the expected objects) is only happening afterwards with huge memory and CPU load (node process maxes 1 core with CPU load during most of the operation).

Well, the 3rd case above is most interesting to me, since it is working, giving me what I want, it just behaves not really understandably.

How come that the "real" work is only done long after I called the update?

I also eliminated write concern/callback in order to speed up the process, and it seems to have helped a little bit.

A typical upsert look something like this:

```
 connectionb.update({ isbn13: book.isbn13 },
     { $addToSet: { ratedByUsers: insertuserrating } },
     { w: 0 });
```

and

```
    connectionu.update(insertuser,
    { $addToSet: { ratedBooks: insertbookrating } },
    { upsert: true, w: 0 });
```

Also, I do not think I have a memory leak, since overall, later on I find the memory to go down back to a few 100MBs again. (Not here - I attribute that to the GC being lazy. I did run the operation repeatedly though and saw that the memory goes down substantially again.)

---

I try to illustrate the behavior better: you can see the 2 peaks in the MySQL CPU consumption, which I would expect since I make 2 queries.

The MongoD peaks irratically.

MongoD and MySQL use very little memory all the time.

The node is running full-1-CPU just about all the time, with the memory first rapidly increasing and then slowly decreasing.

[image: cpu and mem consumption]

I would expect the node.js to do less work and the mongod to be constantly busy trying to insert the data. Also, I am surprised at the timing: node says it is finished with all operations after ~2 minutes (all my code ran through) - but at that point hardly any data is in the mongodb.

Am I doing something wrong?

How to decrease node's memory and CPU consumption and speed up the time by which the data finally arrives in mongodb?

---

Added Real code

(deleted a lot, like models and query which I deem irrelevant). connectionu and connectionb are mongodb connections to the users and books collections.

First, all books are imported, then all users are imported - due to mysql DB structure, I use ratings which determines which users I am interested in and also updates the books collection again with the ratings.

```
    sequelize.query(qstring).success(function (result) {
        var len = result.length;
        result.forEach(function ProcessRatingResult(oneresult) {

            var insertobject = {
                isbn13: oneresult.isbn13,
                title: oneresult.title,
            };
            cntwrite++;
            connectionb.update({ isbn13: oneresult.isbn13 }, insertobject, { upsert: true, w: 0 });
            // only start 2nd part if first part is completely finished - 135s runtime
            if (cntwrite == (len - 1)) {
                // start with slight delay - give mongo/node time to catch up
                setTimeout(ImportRating, 10000); //2500);
            }
        });
    });

    function ImportRating() {
        SQLRating.findAll({ where: {}, include: [SQLUser, SQLBook] }).success(function (sqlresult) {
            async.each(sqlresult, function ProcessRatingResult(oneresult) {
                var book = oneresult.book;
                var user = oneresult.user;
                var rating = oneresult.rating;
                (function (book, user, rating) {
                    var insertuser = {
                        joined: user.created,
                        external_id: user.external_id
                    };

                    var insertbookrating = {
                        book: book.isbn13,
                        rating: rating
                    }

                    connectionu.update(insertuser,
                                { $addToSet: { ratedBooks: insertbookrating } },
                                { upsert: true, w: 0 });

                    var insertuserrating = {
                        user: user.external_id,
                        rating: rating
                    }

                    connectionb.update({ isbn13: book.isbn13 },
                            { $addToSet: { ratedByUsers: insertuserrating } },
                            { w: 0 });
                })(book, user, rating);
            }
                ,
                function (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            );
        });
    }
```

Comment: How are you iterating your input? Probably should be using a stream API. How are you regulating your `.update()` statements in the iteration? You probably need to be using something in the iterator to only call the next item when the update statement is completed on callback. Or at least limit the number of concurrent operations. This is the part of your code that is important. But the graph data seems to indicate you are doing none of these things, hence the build ups and bottlenecks.

Comment: About the iteration: I get an array of results from the sql query. I tried both foreach and async foreach (I tried this to see if the callbacks come when I investigated this), it did not seem to make much difference. I am not regulating at all. How should I? You are correct that the graph hints at this, I have not seen this mentioned anywhere yet though.

Comment: See what you are really being asked to do here is show the relevant parts of your code. Code we can debug and see problems/better approaches in. Paragraphs, not so much so. Editing the question is more useful than more comments.

Comment: I thougt code might complicate things - anything that helps helping me. :) Thanks.

Comment: Okay. Got other things to do and I may get back to this but I see a big "ouch" immediately. Your SQL database call is `.findAll()`, and that means you just pulled everything into an array. Look for the "stream" variant as I said earlier. I also see the complete lack of callbacks on your `.update()` statements which I again mentioned earlier. You need to wait for callbacks, otherwise everything just "loads up". Get back to you later if I can. But look at that.

Comment: I got rid of the callbacks on purpose. At least when I ignored them, they only added to the overhead. Is there any way to use them other thancouting requests/responses and trigger new requests from the responses?      Also, about the streaming from sequelize: I have not found any examples, everything I saw was findAll/success. What to use there? Many thanks!

Comment: I would really look into using bulk operations as they speed up things a lot in my experience. I haven't used Node.js in a  while, but if the driver doesn't support bulk upserts then I would use a different language.